# <Class> object has no attribute

Tags: python, openstack, luigi

I am trying to work on Luigi and Openstack. While calling the class from the main, I am having issues. I am still learning Python but I dont really get the error.

ERROR: AttributeError: 'OpenstackHelper' object has no attribute 'servers

```
password = sys.argv[1]
auth_url = sys.argv[2]
username = sys.argv[3]
tenant_name = sys.argv[4]

class OpenstackHelper(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        pass
    def run(self):
        self.keystone_auth = v2.Password(username=username, password=password, tenant_name=tenant_name,
                                         auth_url=auth_url)
        self.keystone_session = session.Session(auth=self.keystone_auth)

        self.cinder = cinder_client.Client(OS_USERNAME, OS_PASSWORD, OS_TENANT_NAME, OS_AUTH_URL, service_type="volume")
        self.volumes = self.cinder.volumes.list()

        self.snapshots = self.cinder.volume_snapshots.list()

        self.nova = client.Client("2.1", session=self.keystone_session)
        self.servers = self.nova.servers.list()

        self.kwargs = {
            'auth_url': auth_url,
            'session': self.keystone_session,
            'auth': self.keystone_auth,
            'service_type': 'orchestration'}

    def output(self):
        if sys.argv[5] == 'servers':
            print(self.servers)
            return MockFile(self.servers, mirror_on_stderr=True)
        elif sys.argv[5] == 'volume':
            return MockFile(self.volumes, mirror_on_stderr=True)
        elif sys.argv[5] == 'cinder':
            return MockFile(self.cinder, mirror_on_stderr=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     luigi.run(["--local-scheduler"],OpenstackHelper())
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell the line-number/stacktrace in which you are getting the error?

This error means that your class has no variable defined as - 'servers'.
So may be your **output()** function(where you are printing self.servers) is getting called before the line - 
**self.servers = self.nova.servers.list()** in run() function.

Comment: I got error at print(self.servers) inside the output function

Comment: In luigi, output() is run first to check if the output already exists, so that the task run() will not be executed in that case.

Comment: @MattMcKnight But I am calling luigi.run first. As I understand it, shouldnt luigi.run  trigger first and then output function? Or is it that luigi checks the output first to see if the output already exists in which case it wouldnt bother running run function.

Comment: Won't defining self.servers() as None in __init__() do the job?

Comment: No, luigi.run() does not call run() on your task first. It calls output(), then if target exists it skips run(). If output doesn't exist, it calls requires(), after requires() are done, it calls run().

Comment: @Shashank- best not to override __init__() in a Luigi task, especially if he doesn't quite get how it works yet...

Comment: @MattMcKnight, I am getting the picture now. Any tutorial you suggest for Luigi? I am following http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @HeenashreeKhandelwal there was just a PyCon 2017 presentation on it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpkZGXrhZJ8